# Bokeh: linking plots not working for big scales

Tags: python, charts, scatter-plot, bokeh

After modifying the example code found here http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#linking-plots
to have an Y axis with values [0, 500]

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, OpenURL, TapTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="tap,wheel_zoom")

high = 1000

x_values = [i/50 for i in range(0,high)]
y_values = [i/2 for i in range(0,high)]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x = x_values,
    y = y_values,
    color  = ['blue']*len(x_values),
    radius = [0.001]*len(x_values)
    ))

p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', source=source, radius = 'radius')

url = "http://www.colors.commutercreative.com/@color/"
taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)

show(p)
```

--> Clicking on a dot does nothing. Actually, if we manage to click at the exact center of the dot, it works. But not very user-friendly.
Also, for bigger scales (y = [0, 1000]), clicking on the dot has no effect at all.

Interesting fact, I noticed that removing the "radius" keyword fixes the issue. But I do need to specify the radius, so it doesnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this open issue: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/517

Is it possible you can specify a screen `size` in pixels, rather than a `radius` which is in "data space units"? The root of the problem is you have very different data space scales in the x and y dimensions. If not, you might try specifying a different `radius_dimension` to measure along a different dimension:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/reference/models/markers.html#bokeh.models.markers.Circle.radius_dimension

Also please note, the link you gave is to an old version of the docs. If you are actually using an old version of Bokeh, that's fine, just making sure you know in case you think you are looking at the latest docs.

Comment: Thanks I checked the new doc, it is the same code. Also I tried to use size, radius_dimension, radius_units, ... nothing helped. The open issue is from 2014. Seems it has never been resolved ?

Comment: It's a fundamentally mathematical problem with drastically different scales, I'm not sure there is any resolution to be had. I would expect it to work with `size`, can you post updated code?

Comment: changing to `size = [5]*len(x_values)` in the source, and `size="size"` in the glyph works perfectly as expected for me. That's on GH `master` but I am confident it would work on `0.11.1` too.

Comment: Oh ok, indeed I was not using the size properly. Thanks a lot ! Interesting to see that, when zooming, circles don't get bigger when using Size.

Comment: Yes that is specifically the difference, `size` is in pixels (which are constant regardless of zoom level) and `radius` is in "data space" units, which depends on the current range bounds. If you really need `radius` zooming behaviour, another option would be to add invisible squares or rects on top of  all the circles, and attach the tap tools to those, since they do not suffer the same issue when the aspect ratio is large.